# python quiz, picking a random query from a list

Tags: python, random

the problems i am facing with this program are, I'm trying to ask the user questions until the users score questionsright() is equal to 5 right answers. At the moment it just keeps asking questions regardless of score.

And I'm also trying to get the questions to be asked in a random order rather than just straight down the list every time, not sure how to do this. any help is appreciated, thanks

```
import random

def questionchal(questionText, answer):
    if input(questionText + ' ') == answer:
        return True

def gamelist():
    game = input('select a game, game 1, game 2 or game 3 ')
    if game == 'game 1':
        print('okay')
    if game == 'game 2':
        print('okayy')
    if game == 'game 3':
        print('okayyy')

questionsright = 0

#creates a list of questions and their answers
questionList = [
        ('What is my name?' , 'john'),
        ('Where do i live?' , 'uni'),
        ('Am i happy or sad?' , 'happy'),
        ('Am i hungry or full?' , 'hungry'),
        ('Am i alseep or awake?' , 'awake'),
        ('how old am i?' , '19')
    ]

for questionText, answer in questionList:
    while questionchal(questionText, answer) is not True:
        print('Wrong, heres another question!')
    print('Correct! Next question!')
    questionsright +=1
    print(questionsright)

if questionsright <5:
    for questionText, answer in questionList:
        while questionchal(questionText, answer) is not True:
            print('Wrong, heres another question!')
            print('Correct! Next question!')
            questionsright +=1
            print(questionsright)
else:
    print('Thanks for playing')
    gamelist()
```

Comment: `random.shuffle(questionList)`? Also, you have two questions in your "question" and a third in the title - please clarify **what you're actually asking**.

Comment: Im asking how i can randomise the questions that come up.

Comment: im also asking, how i can fix the code so that when the user has answered 5 answers correctly, it stops asking questions and runs the gamelist() function

Comment: Well that's **two questions**. If you get two answers, each of which covers one question, how do you decide which to accept? Please spend a bit of time reviewing [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for? It repeats the set of questions until the amount of right answers is >= 5. However, the way you've written it, it repeatedly asks the same question until you get it right. Is this what you intended?

```
import random

def questionchal(questionText, answer):
    if input(questionText + ' ') == answer:
        return True

def gamelist():
    game = input('select a game, game 1, game 2 or game 3 ')
    if game == 'game 1':
        print('okay')
    if game == 'game 2':
        print('okayy')
    if game == 'game 3':
        print('okayyy')

questionsright = 0

#creates a list of questions and their answers
questionList = [
        ('What is my name?' , 'john'),
        ('Where do i live?' , 'uni'),
        ('Am i happy or sad?' , 'happy'),
        ('Am i hungry or full?' , 'hungry'),
        ('Am i alseep or awake?' , 'awake'),
        ('how old am i?' , '19')
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while questionsright < 5:
        for questionText, answer in questionList:
            while questionchal(questionText, answer) is not True:
                print('Wrong, heres another question!')
            print('Correct! Next question!')
            questionsright +=1
            print(questionsright)

    else:
        print('Thanks for playing')
        gamelist()
```

and if you want it to skip to the next question if the user gets it wrong, you can do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while questionsright < 5:
        for questionText, answer in questionList:
            if questionchal(questionText, answer):
                print('Correct! Next question!')
                questionsright +=1
                print(questionsright)
            else:
                print('Wrong, heres another question!')

    else:
        print('Thanks for playing')
        gamelist()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, skipping the question is useful, the only thing im looking for now is that a random question is picked instead of the question list being followed continuously